# EditText black background color

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my app, all the edit texts I try to apply some custom style, or even just set the background color, are being displayed with black background color.

That is my EditText XML:

```
<EditText
      android:id="@+id/editTextSugestaoReclamacao"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_above="@+id/buttonEnviar_faleConosco"
      android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerLojasLinenarLayout_defaultLoyaltCard"
      android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
      android:gravity="top"
      android:hint="@string/fale_conosco"
      android:inputType="textMultiLine"
      android:background="@drawable/content_layout"
      android:lines="5"
      android:minHeight="150dp"
      android:padding="10dp" >
</EditText>
```

That is the content_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#000000" >
    </stroke>

    <padding
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp" >
    </padding>

    <corners android:radius="2dp" >
    </corners>
</shape>
```

Am I missing something? Could it be some compability problem? I'm using `targetSdkVersion 27`. On Android 5.1.1 works fine, but on Android 7.1.1 not.

[image]

Comment: Did you try it on an actual device or just checking in preview screen? Because code seems fine to me if you want a white background.

Comment: +Kunu I did try on actual device. On Android 5.1.1 works fine, but in Android 7.1.1 the EditText is always displayed with black background.

Comment: i have tested your code and its working fine, could you please post a screenshot of what your are getting? is your content_layout.xml file on the drawable folder? have you any other drawable with the same name on other drawable folder like drawable-v24?

Comment: +Anis BEN NSIR yes, my content_layout.xml is on drawable folder. And I don't have other drawable folder nor other content_layout.xml file. I did create another XML with the same content and different name (edittext_layout.xml) to test and got the same problem.

Comment: Try setting the background programmatically?

Comment: +Quantum_VC Yes, I did try programmatically too. And I got the same problem. It is pretty strange. Anyway, I gave up and took off the background style. The visual is a little bit uggly but, at least I can read what I'm typing on EditText.